# How to define two parent classes for SqlAlchemy entities?

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy

Until now I have a parent class `Entity` for all my orm classes:

```
class AbstractEntity():  

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return AbstractEntity.table_name_for_class(self) 

    ...


Entity = declarative_base(cls=AbstractEntity)
```

---

```
class Drink(Entity):
    name = Entity.stringColumn()
```

I want my classes only to inherit from a single class `Entity`, not from a class `Base` and a mixin `Entity`. That works fine.

However, now I would like to introduce another parent class `EntityAssociation` that I can use as parent for all my asssociation classes that are used for many to many relationships, e.g.

```
class DrinkIngretients(EntityAssociation):
    drink_id = Entity.foreign_key(Drink)
    ingredient_id = Entity.foreign_key(Ingredient)
    ...
```

The class `EntityAssociation` should inherit from Base = declarative_base() but not from  `AbstractEntity`. (It should not include the column `id` that is defined in `AbstractEntity`.)

=> How can I implement that inheritance structure?

I tried

```
class AbstractEntity():  

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(self):
        return AbstractEntity.table_name_for_class(self) 

    ...

Base = declarative_base()

class Entity(Base, AbstractEntity):
    pass

class EntityAssociation(Base):
    pass
```

However, the behavior of

```
Entity = declarative_base(cls=AbstractEntity)
```

and

```
class Entity(Base, AbstractEntity):
    pass
```

seems to be different.

> Class  does not have a **table** or **tablename** specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.

=> How can I specify that the classes Entity and EntityAssociation should not have extra table names?

=> Any other suggestions on how to get the wanted inheritance structure?

Answer (score 0):

The `__abstract__` flag did the trick:

```
class EntityRelation(Base):   
    __abstract__ = True

class Entity(Base, AbstractEntity): 
    __abstract__ = True
```